# Avoiding n+1 with where query active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking at my server log and there's a lot of `SELECT` statements from a particular query. I'm aware of [n+1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) issues and this seems to be one. However I'm not sure what the solution would be for this query. Is this a single query or multiple for every user that is returned (I believe `WHERE` is a single query)?

```
User.where(profile_type: self.profile_type).where.not(id: black_list)
```

EDIT:

`user.rb`

```
  def suggested_friends
    black_list = self.friendships.map(&:friend_id)
    black_list.push(self.id)
    return User.where(profile_type: self.profile_type).where.not(id: black_list)
  end
```

`index.json.jbuilder`

```
json.suggested_friends @user.suggested_friends do |friend|
  json.set! :user_id, friend.id
  json.(friend.profile, *friend.profile.attributes.keys)
end
```

the issue was leaving out the `includes(:profile)`. Using the following query solved my problem

```
User.where(profile_type: self.profile_type).where.not(id: black_list).includes(:profile)
```

thank you for the comments to point me in the right direction

Comment: Can you post more code?  What is self in this situation?  What is `black_list`?  How did you get whatever is in the black_list variable?

Comment: what is `self.profile_type` and `black_list`?

Comment: This will generate a single SQL query.  However, you may be calling this line of code multiple times.  I think you need to add some more context.

Comment: You may be looking at the wrong code. There are a number of gems which tell you exactly where in the code your query is coming from. For example: https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace

Comment: Look for loops in your code. Also look for use of the results of such queries which find associated objects. For example, if you assigned the above to ```results``` then look for things like ```user.permission.role``` or ```user.permissions.all do ...```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.where(profile_type: self.profile_type).where.not(id: black_list)
```

Is only 1 query, even if you have multiple `where` clauses, `rails` is smart to make from it 1 `sql` query.

If you had

```
users = User.where(profile_type: self.profile_type)
users.each do |u|
   u.get_all_comments
end
```

This is n+1 query, because you ask for all `users`, then for each `user` you make new request for its `comments`, this is N (queries for comments) and 1 query for all users